# Upload ffmpeg file output to AWS s3 using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

The `ffmpeg.output("path/file.mp4")` need a `string` path as an argument to write the output file to it. But s3 `bucket.upload(parms, ...)`  need a Binary File as a value to the `Body:` in parms JSON

**Problem:** Unable to provide file data using the file path to s3 bucket in NodeJS Environment

```
FFmpeg()
  .input("source.mp4") //video
  .setStartTime(startTime)
  .setDuration(duration)
  .output(output)    //output file path: string
  .on("end", function() {
    console.log("Processing finished successfully");
    var params = {
      Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
      Key: "videos/filename.mp4",
      Body: output    //binary file data to be provided not file path
    };
    const bucket = new S3({
      accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      region: process.env.S3_REGION
    });
    bucket.upload(params, function(err, data) {
      console.log(err, data);
    });
  })
  .run();
```

Comment: `output` also accepts a stream. https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#outputtarget-options-add-an-output-to-the-command. `aws-sdk` also allows you to pass a stream as `Body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done using `fs.readFileSync()` that provided me the file buffer which I passed to `putObject()`

```
import fs = require("fs");

const inputPath = "source.mp4"
const outputPath = "clip.mp4";

FFmpeg()
  .input(inputPath)            //input video path or URL
  .setStartTime(2)
  .setDuration(2)
  .output(outputPath)          //output file path: string
  .on("end", function() {
    console.log("Processing finished successfully");
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(outputPath);
    var params = {
      Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
      Key: "videos/clip.mp4",
      Body: fileContent        //got buffer by reading file path
    };
    const bucket = new S3({
      accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      region: process.env.S3_REGION
    });
    bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
      console.log(err, data);
    });
  })
  .run();
```

Comment: is it possible to get file directly from s3([pre-signed url) (just pass s3 file url ) instead local path and same for upload (pre-signed url) ?

Comment: @kuldeepchopra I think we can use the pre-signed URL from S3 as the input path, but did you find a solution to upload the outputted file directly to S3?

Comment: @HaseebBurki, for me it is not working, so i keep it simple just upload in multipart s3 because file size is 10gb